# Extract row indices of a dataframe whose entries correspond to rows of another dataframe

Tags: r

I've been struggling for a while now and I can't find a way out. Here's my problem.

I have 2 dataframes:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:10,20,rep=TRUE)))
    df1
      X1 X2 X3
   1  10  1  9
   2   3  4  2
   3   7  6  8
   4   8 10  7
   5   5  7  5
   6   8  5  9
   7   9  8  4
   8   6  2  7
   9   2  9  6
   10  5  2  9

  df2 <- data.frame(df1[sample(nrow(df1),4), ])
  df2
     X1 X2 X3
  8   6  2  7
  3   7  6  8
  10  5  2  9
  7   9  8  4
```

I would like to create a vector *x* of *length(x) = length(df1)* containing, per each row of *df1*, the row index of the corresponding row in *df2* (i.e. same exact values for each column between *df1* and *df2*).

Consider that:

```
    dim(df1)
    [1] 1096188  3 

    dim(df2)
    [1] 256  3
```

and that *df1* has several rows with the same values (i.e. the corresponding row index will be the same), and that in principle all the rows in *df1* should find a match with the row in *df2*.

The expected output would be:

```
    x
   [1] 0 0 2 0 0 0 4 1 0 3
```

Hope this was clear enough...

Can you help?

Thanks,

Piera

Comment: Nope. I need a new vector of the same length of df1, that contains the row index of df2 whose entries are exactly the same of df1. So, in the end, I'll have, per each row of df1, the row index of the corresponding line in df2. Of course, df1 will have several rows with the same values, therefore the row index associated will be the same.

Comment: Yes sorry, I think the example might be improved. My df1 has several rows with the same values. I should clarify that.

Comment: Can you post your expected output from the example given? I assume it is `[1] 8 3 10 7`

Comment: Done! :) Edited as required.

Comment: @CathG Done. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Piera. Yes, much clearer thank you and that is what I understood at first so this is what my answer is giving you. That is not what you get with nicola's answer

Comment: I don't see a comment saying it, so: `length` of a data.frame is the number of columns, not rows. By the way, removing your [tag:dataframes] tag because you ought to use [tag:data.frame]. Finally, set the seed when making random data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just try:

```
 x <- rownames(df2)[match(do.call(paste, df1), do.call(paste, df2))]
 x[is.na(x)] <- 0
```

There is quite a discussion on what it's the desired output; in @CathG interpretation, this line produces it:

```
 match(do.call(paste, df1), do.call(paste, df2),nomatch=0)
```

Comment: This one works as well! :) Thanks, I havn't seen it before! And it's also easy... Thanks again.

Comment: acutally, I'm trying to do some benchmark and didn't get the expected output with your function. I think you should replace `rownames(df2)` by `(1:nrow(df2))` it seems less "dangerous"...

Comment: I really couldn't be sure reading the OP if he wanted the row index or the row name. By the fact the his `df2` does have row names, I opted for this solution. If OP jumps in and states clearly what he wants, I'll change if needed.

Comment: Uhm.. Actually, I get the correct values with this function, but the results from the data.table approach are different...

Comment: @Piera do you need the indices of the df1 rows that are present in df2 or the indices of df2 rows ? nicola's answer gives you the first (but only because df2 is constructed based on df1) and I give you the second ones

Comment: @Nicola I need the row.index, but since in my df the row.names and the index are the same, your solution worked fine for me. Sorry for all the mess...

Comment: @CathG that's why with your solution I get different values: those correspond to the row.names of the ordered df. Am I correct?

Comment: @Piera.  Yes, probably. I prefer to talk with indices than rownames. rownames can be anything...

Comment: with the data provided, your output is `[1] "0" "0" "3" "0" "0" "0" "7" "8" "0" "10"` ..., not `[1] 0 0 2 0 0 0 4 1 0 3` as stated in the (edited) question as desired output

Comment: I didn't follow the whole discussion, but I saw that several times you said that my function doesn't return the desired output when I see that OP said quite the contrary... Maybe I missed something. Of course I can edit, but just out of curiosity, where the OP said that my answer doesn't produce the desired output?

Comment: it's based on the desired output provided by the OP: if you try your solution with `rownames` with the df2 provided in the question, whose rownames are `c("8", "3", "10", "7")`, you're not getting the desired output (but it works ok if rownames correspond to row indices). your former solution only works if the rownames are 1, 2, ... working directly with the indices is safer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an option with `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)

# first set the original orders (data.frame will be sorted when doing setkey)
setDT(df1)[, ori := .I]
setDT(df2)[, ind_df2 := .I]

# define keys
setkey(df1, X1, X2, X3)
setkey(df2, X1, X2, X3)

# compute the indices of the df1 line in df2
x <- df2[df1, ind_df2]
# put the nomatch to 0
x[is.na(x)] <- 0

# Finally, put the original orders back and delete the variable ori
x <- x[order(df1$ori)]
df2 <- df2[order(df2$ind_df2)]
df1[, ori:=NULL]
df2[, ind_df2:=NULL]
```

resulting x (with your data):

```
x
#[1] 0 0 2 0 0 0 4 1 0 3
```

**Another, more simple and efficient option, suggested by @Frank:**

```
setkeyv(setDT(df2)[,ii:=.I],setdiff(names(df2),"ii"))
x <- df2[df1]$ii
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
```

***Some benchmark between @nicola answer, @Frank suggestion and my answer, on a 100000 rows df1 and 200 rows df2***, *with a slight modification of nicola's answer to get the desired output (both functions give the same result, except the need for `as.numeric` for nicola's):*

so:

```
set.seed(17)
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:100,100000,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(df1[sample(nrow(df1),200), ])

nicola <- function(){x<-match(do.call(paste,df1),do.call(paste,df2), nomatch=0)}

cath <- function(){
          dt1 <-data.table(df1); dt1[, ori:=.I]
          dt2 <- data.table(df2); dt2[, ind_df2:=.I]
          setkey(dt1, X1, X2, X3)
          setkey(dt2, X1, X2, X3)
          x <- dt2[dt1, ind_df2]
          x[is.na(x)] <- 0
          x <- x[order(dt1$ori)]
          x
        }

Frank <- function(){dt1 <-data.table(df1);dt2 <- data.table(df2); setkey(setDT(dt2)[,ii:=.I],X1,X2,X3); x <- dt2[dt1]$ii;x[is.na(x)] <- 0}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(cath(), Frank(), nicola(), unit="relative", times=100)
    #Unit: relative
    # expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval cld
  #Frank()  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000  1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100 a  
  # cath()  3.238195  3.099896 2.438342  2.767165 2.177365 1.447397   100  b 
 #nicola() 13.127820 12.476996 8.761549 10.899191 7.292086 2.783436   100   c
```

Comment: This one works!! Thank you very much! I'm just getting an error when I try to reorder it in the original form; it tells me: Error in order(df1$ori) : argument 1 is not a vector

Comment: it works now! And it is also fast!! The problem was that I run it a first time and got few errors since I needed to change the names of the df, and then I did not re-run everything apparently, so the ori was already gone. Super! Thanks again!

Comment: that's the great thing about data.table, it uses binary search with is thousand times faster than "regular" search ! :-). I'm glad it works for you. If you often work with big data.frame like that, you may want to dig into data.table a bit more ;-)

Comment: Great benchmark. Anyway, if you are correct that `1:nrow(df2)` is right instead of `rownames(df2)`, the subset part of my answer is useless, and just `match(..., nomatch=0)` will suffice. After this change, I guess that both options will be similar in efficiency.

Comment: Instead of `1:nrow()` Just use `.I`

Comment: @nicola. I do not agree, the OP is not interested in the "rownames" but in the indices. with your solution I don't get the desired output. I do with `x<-(1:nrow(df2))[match(do.call(paste,df1),do.call(paste,df2))]` though

Comment: Hmmm..  Sorry, not sure what you mean as I see it being used twice in your answer... But Im looking from the phone so probably missing something

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm the one sorry because I totally forgot about the 2 first lines :-/, I thought you were talking about the proposed modification of nicola's solution... Thanks !!

Comment: @nicola I updated the benchmark with the modification of your solution with just `match(..., nomatch=0)`. It doesn't really change the performance differences.

Comment: @Frank thanks fro your comment ! so making the thing more direct... but the order changes then and you get the indices for the ordered df2. or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the rows in df1 don't all have a match in df2 (e.g. row 1).  However, assuming they did (perhaps there are rows in df1 that occur multiple times), you could have:

```
x <- rep(0, length(df1[, 1]) #initialise
for(r1 in 1:length(df1[, 1])){
  for(r2 in 1:length(df2[, 1])){
    if(identical(df1[r1,], df2[r2,])){
      x[r1] <- r2
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Any rows in df1 which in fact aren't in df2 would remain with value 0.  Perhaps not the quickest solution - how many times do you need to repeat the process?

Comment: Not sure why it is not working: I got all 0s, even though I checked and I have matching rows, so it shouldn't.

Comment: It's working for me although weirdly each time I regenerate df2 and re-run I get a similar but non-identical result for x.  Could be an issue with `sample`?

Comment: No idea. I'm using my original data frames and I was getting all 0s... Can't understand why, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a new answer to a very old question, but what is wrong with

```
match(data.frame(t(df1)), data.frame(t(df2)))
```

??

The output is

```
[1] NA NA  2 NA NA NA  4  1 NA  3
```

So there are `NA`s instead of `0`s but otherwise I think it's a one-liner, and no need for `do.call()` or anything either.